# In $ \mathsf{ZFC} $, is it true that $ \text{cf}(\kappa) < \text{cf}(2^{\kappa}) $ for all cardinals $ \kappa $?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

> **Question.** In $ \mathsf{ZFC} $, is it true that $ \text{cf}(\kappa) < \text{cf}(2^{\kappa}) $ for all cardinals $ \kappa $?

I am particularly interested in the case when $ \kappa = \mathfrak{c} \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} 2^{\aleph_{0}} $.

Comment: Of course: $\mathrm{cf}(\kappa)\le\kappa<\mathrm{cf}(2^\kappa)$, where the strict inequality is a consequence of [König's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_%28set_theory%29).

Comment: @Berrick: When talking about cardinals it can be also perfectly clear to write $2^\omega$. Since no ordinals are mentioned here, I find your edit to be unnecessary.

Comment: @Andres: Perhaps post this as an answer?

Comment: @Asaf: Done. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A particular case of Koenig's theorem states that if $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal, then $\kappa^{\mathrm{cf}(\kappa)}>\kappa$. Applying this result when $\kappa=2^\lambda$ gives us that $\mathrm{cf}(2^\lambda)>\lambda\ge\mathrm{cf}(\lambda)$, because 
 $$ (2^\lambda)^\lambda=2^{(\lambda\times \lambda)}=2^\lambda. $$

This result uses choice, of course. It seems problematic to define cofinality for non-well-orderable cardinals, but note that it is consistent (with the absence of choice) that the reals are a countable union of countable sets, which can be reasonably interpreted as saying that $\mathrm{cf}(\mathfrak c)=\omega$.

Comment: Ok, I think cf$\lambda \geq$cf$(2^\lambda)$ implies $\lambda \geq$cf$(2^\lambda)$ implies $2^\lambda =(2^\lambda)^\lambda \geq (2^\lambda)^{cf(2^\lambda)}$, contradicting Konig Theorem.

Comment: Let $\tau=2^\lambda$. I argued that $\tau^\lambda=\tau$. However, Koenig's theorem gives us that if $\rho=\mathrm{cf}(\tau)$, then $\tau^\rho>\tau$. Thus $\tau^\rho>\tau^\lambda$, and therefore $\tau>\lambda$.

Comment: (The last sentence in the comment above should've been "and therefore $\rho>\lambda$.")

Comment: Dear Professor - I had wanted to increase the bounty I had just give. But the system is unrelentingly unforgiving. So here goes. Always appreciative of your most generous participation here. Best regards,

Comment: Thank you for your generosity, @Andrew.